# 3 Forms, close 2nd and open 3rd

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 Forms

```
//Example:
public Form 1;
public Form 2;
public Form 3;
```

When i start my program it's in Form1.
I open Form2 from Form1

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
this.Hide() //Save in memory
f2.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

So in Form2. I open form3

```
Form2 f3 = new Form2();
this.Close() //Trying Destroy Form2 and open Form3.
f3.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

Lastly, i would like to open new Form2 (reload all data) from Form3
But i failed to do so. how to fix it?

Comment: If you are wanting Form2 to reload data, just use Form3 as a dialog from Form2 and trigger the change via properties returned on close. You shouldn't open a 2nd instance of Form2 unless you are really wanting 2 instances.

Comment: How should i refresh the Form2? @ChrisFannin can provide example code?

Comment: Mark Hall provided a decent example below, although I would've gone a slightly different route. As it is very late, I can't work up my own example right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `this.Show()` after calling `f3.ShowDialog()` because ShowDialog() opens a modal window which blocks all other UI threads so any statements following it won't get executed until the modal window is closed.

Comment: Yes. So what should i do in order to achieve my task?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you are using for a data source or how you are updating your 2nd Form. I personally would have everything based off of the First form using the dialog result value to determine whether to reload the 2nd Form.

Something like this:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 f2;
    Form3 f3;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.FormClosing += F2_FormClosing;
        this.Hide();
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void F2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Form2)sender).DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            f3 = new Form3();
            f3.FormClosing += F3_FormClosing;
            f3.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Visible = true;
        }

    }

    private void F3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Form3)sender).DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            f2 = new Form2();
            f2.FormClosing += F2_FormClosing;
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**Form3**

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    string myData;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string getData
    {
        get
        {
            return myData;
        }
        set
        {
            myData = value;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like,

In form 2

```
Form3 f3 = new Form3();
f3.show(); //shouldn't use ShowDialog since it will block the thread
this.close();
```

In form 3, just create a new instance of Form2 and show it as you want.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.showDialog();
```